# Firestore uploading larger rules file results in "Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument."

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to deploy a larger rules files to Firestore. The rules file is currently at 55KB (well below Firestore's listed limit of 256KB). Every time I attempt to simply deploy the rules by themselves using this command...

```
firebase deploy --only firestore:rules --debug
```

I get this  error...

```
Error: HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument.
[2020-09-13T19:29:41.552Z] Error Context: {
  "body": {
    "error": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "body": {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
      }
    },
    "headers": {
      "vary": "X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "date": "Sun, 13 Sep 2020 19:29:41 GMT",
      "server": "ESF",
      "cache-control": "private",
      "x-xss-protection": "0",
      "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "alt-svc": "h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"",
      "accept-ranges": "none",
      "transfer-encoding": "chunked"
    },
    "request": {
      "uri": {
        "protocol": "https:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "firebaserules.googleapis.com",
        "port": 443,
        "hostname": "firebaserules.googleapis.com",
        "hash": null,
        "search": null,
        "query": null,
        "pathname": "/v1/projects/brianneisler-test:test",
        "path": "/v1/projects/brianneisler-test:test",
        "href": "https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/brianneisler-test:test"
      },
      "method": "POST"
    }
  }
}
```

I ran through a test where i commented out all of the rules code and then slowly uncommented portions of it based on dependency (looking for a problematic line). However, what I noticed is that as I uncommented more and more code the problem started happening more frequently. At first it would fail 1 in 5 times. Uncomment more code, started failing more frequently. This leads me to believe that there is some kind of race condition based on compilation time on Firebase's side since the size of the file remained the same, only the code that was uncommented changed.

I have reached out to Firebase's support team and they have verified that there are no errors in the rules themselves. They have been able to reproduce the error but their suggestions of how to workaround the issue have not worked. Here's the response I received from their support team.

> Thanks for the detailed information. I made some tests using the rules you shared, it seems that the rules have the correct syntax, but there are too many rules to update in the Firebase console at a time.
>
> One option is uploading the rules in chunks. First, try uploading the first 1500 lines of the rules and publish the rules. After that add the rest code lines, it should be like 400, and publish the rules once again, it should not send the error this time.
>
> I also tried deploying the rules using the Firebase CLI. When I tried to deploy the functions the first time it showed me the same error as you, but I tried to deploy the functions one more time and it did it correctly.

It's clear they're running into the same issue where this will occasionally fail.

Has anyone else run into this issue and figured out a way to work around it?

Comment: As far as I know, the only workarounds are the ones mentioned by the Firebase team, of uploading in parts, to avoid the issue, as they mentioned, it's indeed related to the size of the file/number of lines. I would believe there isn't much else to do it, as it's the official solution/alternative provided by the support.

Comment: Is this still a problem? The 256KB limit isn't really a 256KB limit?

Answer (score 0):

### Current workaround

If i minimize the rules using the [firemin](https://github.com/brianneisler/firemin) rules minifier, the deployment succeeds more often. This makes sense since it collapses single use functions and overall reduces the size of the rules file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. There is some interesting info about the file size limit here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/06/new-firestore-security-rules-features.html. Excerpt: "To be more specific, the compiled AST of the rules file had to be smaller than 64 KB". So it sounds like the file limit is after the file is compiled by Firebase. Is there still an advantage to be had by minifying?